# Hashicorp vault: Multiple Applications and Multiple service accounts - prevent another app from using different svc account

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-security

I have a Vault deployment in my cluster that I use to store secrets. Additionally, I have created `roles`, `policies`, and a `ServiceAccount`. My applications will retrieve secrets from Vault using this service account. However, I am concerned that another application could use the service account meant for a different application. What measures can I take to prevent this from happening?

Say, I have assigned different policies to `application A` and `application B`, so I need a way to ensure that `application B` cannot use the `ServiceAccount` meant for `application A`.

Comment: This would depend heavily upon the chosen authentication engine.

Comment: I have chosen k8s auth method. Is there something better that might help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `kubernetes` auth method, this is how it works. You don't need to do anything else. Assuming you are using the default behavior of kubernetes where it creates a service account per app, you're good.

When an app logins to Vault using a ServiceAccount, it provides its token and authenticates for a specific role, e.g

```
curl \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"jwt": "<your service account jwt>", "role": "demo"}' \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
```

The SA token is available only to your service. Kubernetes creates a SA for each app. It means AppA doesn't have the access for AppB ServiceAccount token (unless you explicitly specify that).

The way to integrate that with Vault is to config a **named role** with a **bounded service account and namespace**

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/demo \
    bound_service_account_names=myapp \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
    policies=default \
    ttl=1h
```

The above role can be used to authenticate only for `myapp` from the `default` namespace. No other app can login using this role.

To address your question, you would need a **different Vault role** for each app, with **different bounded service account and namespace**.

Check out Vault documentation on [kubernetes auth method](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/auth/kubernetes) for full example

Comment: (Editing) Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I have sort of done this already. My confusion, particularly is - what stops other app from using this service account. All apps are packages as Helm charts, and one person can simple give SVC-Account name as any account he wants. Is there any way to restrict this - apart from code review (i.e how can app authenticate itself before it can use a Svc account).

Comment: You need to govern who has access to deploy apps, and where (namespaces). You can check additional tools such as Kyverno to configure restricted policies - https://kyverno.io/policies/other/restrict-service-account/restrict-service-account/

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. Marking this as resolved (The comment helped a lot)